How to find a max value in a dictionary in Power Point Application?
The following code works properly in Excel.
But I am looking for Power Point solution.
How to find a max value in a dictionary in Power Point Application?
    Sub Macro1()
    
        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        For i = 1 To 10
            dict.Add Key:=i, Item:=i
        Next i
        
        For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
           Debug.Print dict.Keys()(i), dict.Items()(i)
        Next i
        
        'The following two lines works properly in Excel. 
        'But I am looking for Power Point solution.
        Debug.Print Application.Max(dict.Items)
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(dict.Items)
    
    End Sub


This will work in Powerpoint:
Sub Macro1()
    
        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 10
            dict.Add Key:=i, Item:=i
        Next i
        
        Dim iMax As Long
        For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
           Debug.Print dict.Keys()(i), dict.Items()(i)
           If dict.Items()(i) > iMax Then iMax = dict.Items()(i)
        Next i
        
        Debug.Print iMax
    End Sub

You have to check for the max value within a loop.

In Excel-VBA, WorksheetFunction is a way to access functions that Excel provides (not VBA). There is no such function in Powerpoint.
So your best bet is to loop over all entries of your dictionary:
Dim key As Variant, maxValueKey As Variant, maxValue As Variant
For Each key In dict.keys
    If IsEmpty(maxValue) Or dict(key) > maxValue Then
        maxValue = dict(key)
        maxValueKey = key
    End If
Next key
Debug.Print "The max value found = " & maxValue & " at key " & maxValueKey


Yeah, SO has become a race for early answers, so it's getting more and more useless to try to explain something or trying to optimize code or the like.

Set a Reference to the Microsoft Excel 14.0/16.0 Object Library and after it all the WorksheetFunction functions are avail.

Thank you very much.  After adding Excel Reference this works:       Debug.Print Excel.Application.max(dict.Items) And this also works: Debug.Print Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.max(dict.Items)


Catch the max value with UDF

Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim dict As Object, i As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        dict.Add Key:=i, Item:=i
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print dict.Keys()(i), dict.Items()(i)
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print GetMax(dict.Items())
    
End Sub

Function GetMax(arr) As Long
    Dim maxVal As Long, i As Long
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        maxVal = -1000000000#
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If maxVal < arr(i) Then maxVal = arr(i)
        Next
        GetMax = maxVal
    Else
        GetMax = arr
    End If
End Function



Pls remember to initialize the maxVal with a small number (negative) before looping, otherwise you may miss the max if all values are negative in dict.
